# Rewriting Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.4

I have run into a problem where shipping options are not making it to the PayPal Express review page.  If the buyer enters a free shipping coupon and then uses PayPal Express, when they return from the PP website, the review page where the submit the order doesn't have the free shipping option.

[I found a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894591/shipping-not-transferring-to-paypal-express-with-magento-1-4-2) where this was answered by adding code to the Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout class.  This change works, but modifying core code is a no-no, so I'm trying to rewrite the class and I'm having trouble.  I've rewritten core classes before, but this one is different somehow and I can't figure it out.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

here's the contents of my config.xml.  Does this look right?

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <VPS_Paypal>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </VPS_Paypal>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <paypal>
                <rewrite>
                    <express_checkout>
                        <class>VPS_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout</class>
                    </express_checkout>
                </rewrite>
            </paypal>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but based on the class name I would think that adding this to the  section of your config would work:

```
        <paypal>
            <rewrite>
                <express_checkout>Your_Model_Class_Here</express_checkout>
            </rewrite>
        </paypal>
```

Your custom class should extend Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout and only override the method you want to change.

Comment: That's what I tried initially.  I went back and tried including all the code from the Checkout.php file into my custom class, but it still doesn't work.  I turned on error display and it's throwing a stack trace with this error: **Fatal error: Call to a member function getCheckoutShortcutImageUrl() on a non-object in /home/.../app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Express/Shortcut.php**.  I've added the contents of my config.xml to the original message.  Let me know if that looks right and if you have any other ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, I figured out part of my issue.  You're not supposed to have <class> elements when you're rewriting a module.  I knew that and didn't do it on my other ones but I had a brain fart this time.  I think it's working now...I'll post a followup if I have any issues